# How to access data in shared docker volume on a jupyter notebook server using Google Colab?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am running a jupyter notebook server using docker. I connect to the server using Google Colab. I create a shared volume between the host and the server.

I can access the data with the code in the notebook, but when I want to open files in the Google Colab environment in my browser, I get the following error:
[image]

I start the server, using the following command:

```
docker run --gpus all -p 8888:8888 -v C:\Users\Sascha\Documents\Docker:/tf -it --rm tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/tf --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

How do I need to update the docker command, to allow the access from the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the host blocks the access when trying to open files within colab, that are located on the host.

To allow access to all origins, the following comand can be used:

```
--NotebookApp.allow_origin='*'
```